# Flexbox children with flex-height and width: 100%

Tags: html, css, flexbox

The code below shows a `<parent>` container consisting of some `<child>` items.

The  `<child>` items are positioned inside the `<parent>` item with the `.flex` property *(see display: flex in the parent)* so they exactly fill out the parent element. All this works fine so far.

However, I want to achieve now that the `display: flex` property **only applies to the height** of the `<child>` items so they exactly fit into the parent element vertically.

For the **width** I want each of the `<child>` items at **100%** of the surrounding parent so in the end they are displayed as a block *(below each other and not next to each other)*.

What do I have to change in my code to achieve this?

You can also find my code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/onmotyvo/2/)

```css
html { 
height: 100%; 
}

body { 
height: 100%; 
}

.parent {
  height: 80%;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  
  display: flex;

    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    background-color: blue;
}

.parent div {
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex: 1;

    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div> 1.0 Menu </div>
  <div> 2.0 Menu </div>
  <div> 3.0 Menu </div>
  <div> 4.0 Menu </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change to `flex-direction: column` and they will stack vertically, like block element does, and the `flex: 1` will apply for their height.

Also, the `justify-content` should be set on the `parent` as it is a property of the flex container, though as you use `flex: 1` on the flex-item, it won't affect anything.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.parent {
  height: 80%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;

  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.parent div {
  flex: 1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div> 1.0 Menu </div>
  <div> 2.0 Menu </div>
  <div> 3.0 Menu </div>
  <div> 4.0 Menu </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I was looking for. I also edited here https://jsfiddle.net/onmotyvo/5/

Answer (score 1):

> However, I want to achieve now that the display: flex property only applies to the height of the   items so they exactly fit into the parent element vertically.
>
> For the width I want each of the  items at 100% of the surrounding parent so in the end they are displayed as a block (below each other and not next to each other).

Change the `flex-direction` from the default `row` to `column`

```
flex-direction:column;
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
}

.parent {
  height: 80%;
  width: 100%;
  /* float: left;  not required */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; /* set this */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.parent div {
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex: 1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div> 1.0 Menu </div>
  <div> 2.0 Menu </div>
  <div> 3.0 Menu </div>
  <div> 4.0 Menu </div>
</div>
```